# Non trivial homomorphism into injective envelope of a simple composition factor

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory, injective-module

Let $A$ be an artin algebra and let mod$(A)$ be the category of finitely generated $A$-modules.

> Let $S$ be a simple module and let $M \in$ mod$(A)$. We further assume that $S$ is a composition factor of $M$. Then there exists a non trivial homomorphism $M \rightarrow I(S)$, where $I(S)$ is the injective envelope of $S$.

What I have so far:
We just need to show that there is a non trivial momomorphism $S \rightarrow M$. If we have that, then the existence of a non trivial homomorphism $M \rightarrow I(S)$ follows from the infectivity of $I(S)$.

So let $S$ be a composition factor of $M$. Then there exist submodules $L \subseteq K$ of $M$, such that $S \cong K/L$. Now one needs to construct a non trivial monomorphism $g: K/L \rightarrow M$. Thats the point where I have trouble continuing the proof. Intuitively I would say we construct $g$ by $k+L \mapsto k$. But I don't think it is a well defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not necessarily a nontrivial monomorphism $S\to M$.

But there is a nontrivial homomorphism $K\to I(S)$: namely, the composition of the obvious maps $K\to K/L\cong S\to I(S)$. And then, by injectivity of $I(S)$, this homomorphism extends to a homomorphism $M\to I(S)$.